# INSERT OVER statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What the difference between

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (values)
```

and

```
INSERT OVER table VALUES (values)
```

?

Comment: +1. Don't know what it does yet but this works for me `create table #test(c int) INSERT OVER #test VALUES (10)`

Comment: @Martin - is it just a replacement for `INTO`?

Comment: @Martin It's totally undocumented in Books Online though! I thought this was a terrible question, but it's actually a great one :-)

Comment: @alex - what prompted you to even try this?

Comment: +1 It works for me too.couldnt find any documentation for this.

Comment: Maybe something to do with composable DML - [unless the author here just used the wrong phrase](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/535753/insert-over-dml-is-not-allowed-on-a-table-with-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: +1, posted this to connect.microsoft.com out of curiosity.

Comment: @GSerg: could you append the link to your item at connect?

Comment: @Chris [Here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/653915/insert-over-syntax).

Comment: Apparently they deleted my post :(

Comment: Hmmm... No, they didn't!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People at Microsoft [say](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/653915/insert-over-syntax):

> Thanks for reporting this issue. We
>   keep recognizing the OVER keyword
>   along with the INTO keyword (with the
>   same meaning) in INSERT statements to
>   provide backward compatibility with
>   the previous versions of SQL Server.
>   This should not present any problem
>   for application development.
>
> Eugene Zabokritski, SQL Engine

Answer (score 8):

Of all reserved keywords, only `INTO` and `OVER` work.

`SQL:2003` mentions `OVERRIDING` keyword to override the identity (currently only supported by `DB2`)

Probably, `SQL Server` parses it for now but does not actually implement.

The plans generated are identical, and `ParameterizedText` is expanded into `INSERT INTO`.

So as for `2008R2`, the answer would be this:

**No difference, except that `INSERT OVER` has already wasted about 50 manhours of most curious developers to the moment and there is more to go**

Comment: @Robert: The `OVER` clause used in the window functions does not seem to deal with this.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  But it is the only Microsoft-defined use of the `OVER` keyword that I can find.

Answer (score 2):

According to this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

INSERT OVER is not part of the defined syntax tree.  Therefore, even if it works, it's probably not officially supported by Microsoft.

Comment: +1 - My guess is it's some sort of accident that they left it on.  Maybe got mixed-up prepositions in the code or something...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `INSERT OVER` is supposed to overwrite an existing row in the table. For this you would actually use

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field=value, field2=value2> WHERE <condition to pinpoint row>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he's after, actually.  It's apparently undocumented syntax for an `INSERT`...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for resurrecting a dead thread, but this shows near the top of a Google search for INSERT OVER. I was hoping to find a better explanation/example here, but this link does a decent job as a starting point. If you're looking for information on the INSERT OVER DML statement (like a Merge command), take a look at this link: https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/11/28/sql-server-2008-insert-over-a-dml-statement/